# Working on a program to manage assets and their locations. (C#/.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, assets

im working on a .NET application that would allow me (and subsequent users) to input audio and picture assets and then organize them on a 2D grid. This was assigned to a 4 person group, of which 2 can program and one (myself) knows C#. None of us have experience making Windows applications and i don't even know what kind of things to Google that will help me out. I was able to "design" a GUI for it (not too hard with Visual Studio) but i have no idea on how to make it import and display assets nor how to make a 2D grid and be able to assign locations there. Any advice/assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You must have covered something in your class/course that would give you a good starting point. Have you asked your teacher/professor for help?

Comment: this really too broad for stack overflow...

Comment: personally I'd go with WPF for windows.....  making grids of stuff is trivial..... you need to look into data binding and templates

Comment: @Keith Nicholas: I would go with WPF too, but perhaps that is too advanced for students in this class/course.

Comment: Thanks, ill try out WPF. This is a capstone project (there's more involved, but that is what i was having trouble with) so i dont have a good starting point and none of my classes ever covered Windows applications and things like this so i don't even know who to ask. I appreciate the help and the comments though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the tool box and Drag Drop a DataGridView onto your winform.

Obviously all the Grid Properties are in the proerties dialogue and if you click the little button in the properties window with the "Lightning Bolt" thats how you add Events.

Then whip up some code to populate the DataGridView, eg (off the top of my head):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Audio Asset");
dt.Columns.Add("Image Asset");

const int audioColIndex = 0;
const int imageColIndex = 1;

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[audioColIndex] = "A MP3";
dr[imageColIndex] = "A picture";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[audioColIndex] = "A MP4";
dr[imageColIndex] = "A image";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

DataGridView1.Datasource = dt;
```

The datatable is just an example to get you going. Better to fetch your data from the database and "bind" your grid to the datasource so that you can unit test your business logic.

The real solution tho is to buy a winform development book, I'm not being condescending or anything but if you cant get started pick up a book. Programming is a fusion of Art, Math, Science & Technology - its a complex subject that you cant google around for all the answers. You have to invest some time in education.

Comment: Although a good idea, I doubt they'll have time to unit test or even know where to begin.

Comment: @Bernard lol, thats why I edited my answer and gave him the REAL solution